# Não acha o HttpContext.Current

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando criar um UrlHelper da seguinte forma:

```
UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
```

Já fiz a referencia a `System.Web`, como vi como solução em vários lugares.

```
using System.Web;
```

O estranho que é esse using está cinza (Visual Studio 2015) o que mostra que ele nem está usando essa referencia.

O erro é:

> Error CS1061  'HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for
>   'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'HttpContextBase' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Comment: você está utilizando qual mvc no vs2015? vnext? se for vnext, pode esquecer o system.web.

Comment: o projeto é mvc 5, asp.net aplication. vs2015, vnext? não sei dizer...

Comment: Tenta assim UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);

Comment: vnext é o mvc6.

Comment: Funcionou! Estranho, pq não funciona com using?

Comment: O Using está certo, o problema é que HttpContext que voce tava puxando era do Controller e nao do SYSTEM.WEB

Comment: você pode user o HttpContext  do controller, é só chamar HttpContext.Request.RequestContext (sem o current), que funciona da mesma forma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19432129/751090):

Para ter uma referência ao `HttpContext.Current` você precisa trocar o termo

```
HttpContext.Current
```

por

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current
```

Isso é porque a classe `Controller` define uma propriedade com o nome `HttpContext`, definida como

```
public HttpContextBase HttpContext { get; }
```

`HttpContext` na classe `Controller` retorna um `HttpContextBase` que não tem a propriedade `Current`.

Por isso você precisa usar o namespace qualificado